# Snapshot complex UIScrollview content view beyond screen bounds to speed up scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am working on an old app (so Obj-C, but that should not make a difference for what I am asking).

It uses a big UIScrollView whose contents are made of several dozen of small views that are either icons or UILabels with text - this helps with the layout. In any case it has been working fine for years, except that with some added background information and color coding, it started making more and more sense to apply a shadow to the text and the icons.

As you know, applying non-fixed shadow like I wanted (around text, or icons with transparency) is a performance hog, so scrolling became jerky. I said, hey, I only need to draw once, I could just snapshot and replace with an image.

My problem is that the only method I found that actually works at getting a UIImage out of this huge (8000x500 points) UIView with its subviews:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.contentSize);
    CGRect savedFrame = scrollView.frame;
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height);

    [scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

is **crazy** slow. Trying on the slowest device I have, an iPad Air 2, it takes over a minute to do the `renderInContext` step!

I tried what are more "modern" methods, e.g. :

```
    UIGraphicsImageRenderer *renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:scrollView.contentSize];
    UIImage *img = [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext * _Nonnull rendererContext) {
            [scrollView drawViewHierarchyInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        }];
```

This gives me a blank (transparent) image, and so does specifying the first subview of the ScrollView which is a container for all the subviews I want. Doing the same with the parent view of the scrollview, gives me an image of just the visible part of the scrollview. The same thing (visible part) is what I get with this as well:

```
UIView *view = [scrollView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

So, I am not sure what else to try, as I want to avoid redoing everything to draw directly on a single UIView, instead of the current model. Any ideas?

TIA

Update: One good idea I had is that for UILabels I replaced the layer shadows with the - not soft but fast - UILabel shadows. OK result in look, good increase in scroll speed. So maybe I should try to increase scroll performance with things like that rather than going the snapshot route...

Comment: Hard to say what you might do to optimize it without seeing example code of what you're doing. But... have you set `shouldRasterize` to true for your shadows?

Comment: @DonMag, yes, that was one of the first things I tried - did not affect things perceivably. My question was mainly about snapshotting, as that's one way you could go and yet it did not work at all for me. In the end I avoided all layer shadows, UILabel shadows work well and for images I am just applying a shadow directly to the image instead, so it's now fast. Still curious though about if snapshotting is possible and I just did not figure it out...

Comment: Well... if you're on a 2x screen-scale device, you're generating a `16,000 x 1,000` pixel image... on a 3x device, a `24,000 x 1,500` pixel image. Those are pretty big, and likely why you get nothing when trying to use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`.